# How do I find out a specific row ID from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I’m working on a project (I’m a total newbie), here ‘s how the project goes…

I’ve created a **Create User** page, the user puts in the credentials and click on **Create Account**.

This redirects to another page (process.php) where all MySQL queries are executed-
Note: `ID` is set to Auto Increment, Not Null, Primary Key. All the data is inserted dynamically, so I don’t know which `Username` belongs to which `ID` and so on.

```
$query = “INSERT INTO users (Username, Something, Something Else) VALUES (‘John’, ‘Smith’, ‘Whatever’ )”
```

Everything gets stored into the “users” table.

Then it gets redirected to another page (content.php) where the User can review or see his/her credentials.

The problem is, I use `SELECT * FROM users` and `mysql_fetch_array()` but it always gives me the User with `ID = 1` and not the current User (suppose user with `ID = 11`). I have no idea how to code this.

There are suppose 50 or more rows,
how can I retrieve a particular row if I don’t know its ID or any of its other field’s value?

Comment: If you don't know ANYTHING about the row you want to get - there's no way other than guessing!?

Comment: But you know his ID, no? If he log in, you will know his ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mysql_fetch_array()` just once, so it is getting you just one row.

what you are writing:

```
 <?php

 include('connection.php'); //establish connection in this file.
 $sql = "select * from users";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 echo(row['id']);

 ?>
```

What should be there to fetch all the rows:

```
 <?php

 include('connection.php'); //establish connection in this file.
 $sql = "select * from users";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     echo(row['id']);
 }

 ?>
```

Now, what you need, is to get the user id of the registered user at that time.

For that, you need to create a session. Add `session_start();` in your `process.php` and create a session there. Now to get the last `id` you have to make a query:

```
 select *  
 from users 
 where id = (select max(id) from users);
```

Now this will give you the last id created. Store that in a session variable.

```
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
```

Now, on content.php add this:

```
 session_start();
 echo($_SESSION['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

Get the ID generated in the last query. Reference: https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id

This function return the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Now you have the `id`, add that to your `WHERE` clause.

Note: It would be better if you use `mysqli`.

Comment: He doesnt need to know last insert_id. He said he wanted to get credentials of specific user (f.e. logged user).

Comment: @Legionar If we get the ID then we can add it to the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = 11
```

If you dont use `WHERE`, it will select all users, and your `mysql_fetch_assoc` will get you one row of all (ie. where ID = 1).

PS: `mysql_*` is deprecated, rather use `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql_ commands:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (`Username`, `Something`, `Something Else`) VALUES ('John', 'Smith', 'Whatever' )";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
header("Location: content.php?id=".$user_id);
```

Or another way to pass $user_id to your next page

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
header("Location: content.php");
```

Using mysqli_ commands:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (`Username`, `Something`, `Something Else`) VALUES ('John', 'Smith', 'Whatever' )";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $query)   or die( printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbConn)) );
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbConn);
```